# Process for migrating Dropbox to SpiderOak

Tags: backup, dropbox, migration

I want to move my data from dropbox to SpiderOak. I have 3 computers running dropbox. But I have a poor WAN connection with very limited upload bandwidth.
So I thought I do as first step install the dropbox client on my server on the internet an download there my data from dropbox. Then after this I upload/backup my data from this server with a broadband connection to SpiderOak. After the backup is completed I setup the sync between my 3 computers so that they will not have to upload the data again.

Will this process work so that I don't have to upload my data again over my WAN connection at home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consultation with the customer support from SpiderOak this procedure will work asassumed